# maven not running all subset of tests I ask it to when using #

Tags: java, maven, junit, automation, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to run a couple of tests from different classes, my command line is:

mvn -Dtest=com.MyComp.Selenium.SelTests.SomeTests1#XTest,com.MyComp.Selenium.SelTests.SomeTests1#YTest,com.MyComp.Selenium.SelTests.SomeTests2#ZTest

When I run this I would expect it to run XTest and YTest from the class SomeTests1 and ZTest from SomeTests2 but instead it just runs XTest and ZTest and skips YTest.

If I just tell it to run YTest or if I tell it to run all tests in SomeTests1 it works. Please can somebody see what I'm doing wrong?

I don't want to run all the tests in each class I just want a subset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Junit 4.x and surefire 2.12.1 or greater then you can use the following syntax for running multiple tests in a class

```
mvn -Dtest=com.MyComp.Selenium.SelTests.SomeTests1#XTest+#YTest...
```

Note the + symbol. Here is the [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/single-test.html)